# How to install Django on uWSGI and Nginx (Mac OS X)

Tags: django, nginx, installation, osx-lion

I'm trying to install all in Mountain Lion, Practically everything is installed and the problem is the configuration.

**Progress:**
MySQL DMG + MySQLdb Compile + Python + brew nginx + brew uwsgi + pip install Django.

**Configuration:**
Path My first project: /Users/poly/Projects >> Django Project myproject/

Now, I tried to do a thousand things but I have not managed to start nginx with uwsgi.

Can you give me a hand please. Thanks.

Comment: This hard without specifics - but I would suggest making uwsgi run in plain HTTP mode first before WSGI (an upstream server like nginx is not required).  See "Force uWSGI to natively speaks HTTP (or fastcgi)" in http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example

Comment: I woud recommend to try gunicorn!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to keep looking, Greetings.

Comment: Instead of *making uwsgi run in plain HTTP*, you can use Django embed HTTP server: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server